# VBA ACCESS Comparing String as they are integer

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, comparison, ms-access-2007

I am trying to prompt the user to input a range and display all the instruments that are within that range in a subform.

Problem: The upper and lower range is a text field (because some of the range cannot be expressed in integer). As seen in the screenshot, the comparison only compare the first character of the field.

User's input: 5 - 3
On the subform: **3**6 - 4 
It compares 5 and 3 instead of 36

I know vba is doing what it has been told but how can I achieve the result I want?

[image]

Here is my code for requering the subform:

```
    Dim Up As Integer
    Dim Low As Integer

        If Me.Text_L = "" Or IsNull(Me.Text_L) Or Me.Text_U = "" Or IsNull(Me.Text_U) Then
            MsgBox ("Please choose a valid range!")
        Else
            Up = Me.Text_U
            Low = Me.Text_L

            SQL = SQL_Origin & " WHERE [qry_View_Search].[Upper_Range] <= '" & Up & "' " _
            & "AND [qry_View_Search].[Lower_Range] >= '" & Low & "';"


            subform_View_Search.Form.RecordSource = SQL
            subform_View_Search.Form.Requery
        End If
```

Comment: You are comparing them as strings, I think you needs to say [upper range]<=" & cint(up) & " AND [qry_view_search...

Comment: If you make the `Upper` and `Lower` fields a floating point datatype (eg Single or Double), instead of text, they can store decimal values.  Then you can do numeric comparisons with actual numbers instead of text.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it gives me the same result :(

Comment: @HansUp Thats the thing, some of the data in this field cannot be expressed in integer. But despite of those data, I still want to compare the rest of the integer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  When `Upper` contains `3.6`, what do you mean by "the rest of the integer"?

Comment: As Nathan_Sav has pointed out - change it the text in the text field to an integer.  Maybe rather than in the SQL do it when you assign the value to up - `Up = CINT(Me.Text_U)`

Comment: maybe I wan't clear enough, the table upper and lower contains some specific range value like "N/A", "3*6*8" these kinds of info. thats why I have to remain the field type in string

Comment: Cast those strings to numbers when they represent valid numbers, or Null otherwise.  So do comparisons similar to this: `IIf(IsNumeric([Upper]), Val([Upper]), Null) <= 5`

Comment: @HansUp Iff statement seems like a good idea for me to start though it gives me the exact same result. \

Comment: The next approach is to create a new column in the query for IIf(IsNumeric([Upper]), Val([Upper]), Null) and use where statement as in my code above to requery it. Though it gives me the same result again~

Answer (score 2):

so what i did is made a new column in the query for 
    `IIf(IsNumeric([Upper]), Val([Upper]), Null)`
to get all the numeric result.

Then in the vba, I re query the subform as below

```
SQL = SQL_Origin & " WHERE [qry_View_Search].[Upper] <= cint(Forms![frm_View_Search]![Text_U]) " _
                                    & "AND [qry_View_Search].[Lower] >= cint(Forms![frm_View_Search]![Text_L]);"
```

Thanks @HansUp !

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully for those cases used Val only:

```
Value: Val([FieldName])
```

or:

```
Value: Val(Nz([FieldName]))
```